# Where to keep intermediate results of a spring batch job?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

For context, I have a table with parcels that were delivered to different delivery countries. I want to find the average parcel count per delivery country per week day(Sun, Mon, Wed etc) for the past 5 weeks.

I am supposed to use Spring Batch for this. From how I see, I could fetch the parcels as batches to do the calculation. But I won't be able to write the final result until I have processed all the parcels. Am I using the wrong concept for batches here? Or does Spring Batch provide a way to keep intermediate results?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but one technique you can use is staging tables. Do intermediate calculations and store results in staging tables. then aggregate the results from those tables. A final step would remove those staging tables to clean up things. As a side note, if it was up to me, I would write a SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Spring batch just triggers code to execute. I would write the results into a explicit **batch database** with all results related to the actual batch run. In that way you do not spam the production database and also might keep the results for further documentation/debugging. If necessary, you may delete it after a certain period. That way, if that batch database gets crashed because of any reason, it won't interfere with production data and you have the data sorted by the batch run.